# Location of cloud fonts from MS Office?

Tags: microsoft-office, fonts

Microsoft Office 365 offers an option for '[cloud fonts](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/cloud-fonts-in-office-f7b009fe-037f-45ed-a556-b5fe6ede6adb)', which are served via an internet connection and cached locally on the user's computer when loaded.

Where on the computer are these font files stored, even temporarily?

Comment: The article lists every font file that exists.  You should be able to download/enable one of those fonts then find the file by searching your system.  You don't specify which OS you are using.

Answer (score 6):

In Windows 10 it is located here:

```
C:\Users\Name of User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\FontCache\4\CloudFonts\
```

Answer (score 2):

In MacOS its located in:

```
~/Library/Group Containers/UBF8T346G9.Office/FontCache/4/CloudFonts
```

Comment: I suspect that's in the user Library, not /Library, as the latter has no Group Container subfolder.